# NumPy: Some operators don't work when __array_ufunc__=None in array-like class

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have followed [this guide](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.classes.html#numpy.class.__array_ufunc__) on implementing objects that can interact with `np.ndarray` through binary operators such as `+`, `-`, `*`, etc...

As recommended for my case, I have set `__array_ufunc__ = None`, and implemented binary operations like `__mul__` and `__div__`. In those examples however, `__mul__` works while `__div__` does not.

Here is a MWE:

```
import numpy as np

class ArrayLike(object):
    __array_ufunc__ = None
    def __mul__(self, other):
       return 'mul'
    def __div__(self, other):
       return 'div'

array = np.arange(3)
npnum = np.float32(2.0)
alike = ArrayLike()

alike * array # 'mul'
alike / array # '*** TypeError: operand 'ArrayLike' does not support ufuncs (__array_ufunc__=None)'
alike * npnum # 'mul'
alike / npnum # '*** TypeError: operand 'ArrayLike' does not support ufuncs (__array_ufunc__=None)'
```

Comment: Just checking, is this python2 or 3? Never mind, I figured it out and have replied the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

```
import numpy as np

class ArrayLike(object):
    __array_ufunc__ = None
    def __mul__(self, other):
       return 'mul'
    def __truediv__(self, other):
       return 'div'

array = np.arange(3)
npnum = np.float32(2.0)
alike = ArrayLike()
alike / npnum # 'div'
```

Notice that I am using `__truediv__` instead of `__div__`. `__div__` is not a valid magic method operator for Python 3, only for Python 2.

For more information, refer to [Python 3 Operators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html)

If this answers your question, be sure to mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, derp! There I am delving deep in to NumPy but it's just a classic Python 2 vs 3 thing. Many thanks for the answer!